# Jake: directory-tasks function not working?

Tags: node.js, jake

Jake's documentation states that directory-tasks create a directory for use with for file-tasks. Jake checks for the existence of the directory, and only creates it if needed.

Example:

> desc('This creates the bar directory for use with the foo-minified.js file-task.');
>
> directory('bar');

I have not been able to get this to work inside or outside of a file-task. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I was running Node v0.5.0-pre and updated to v0.6.6. Still no luck. I've filed an official ticket, but see if anyone knows if I've just been using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I just wrote and am using:

```
/* Checks if directory exists, creates if needed with optional created callback. */
function directory(dir, callback){
    if (!path.existsSync(dir)){
        console.log(dir + " folder doesn't exist. Creating...");
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        if (callback){
            callback(dir);
        }
    }
}
```